# Display data in dynamic matrix format using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will get the below json from webapi and I need to display this data in matrix format on UI. How would I do this?

The json data looks like this:

```
[
 {"ShippingLine_Cd":"AAC","SizeType_Cd":"20BU","ERIStatus_Cd":"Active","Shift_Nbr":"1"},
 {"ShippingLine_Cd":"ACL","SizeType_Cd":"20BU","ERIStatus_Cd" :"Active","Shift_Nbr":"2"},
 {"ShippingLine_Cd":"AMA","SizeType_Cd":"20DR","ERIStatus_Cd" :"Active","Shift_Nbr":"1"},
 {"ShippingLine_Cd":"ABC","SizeType_Cd":"20DR","ERIStatus_Cd" :"Pending","Shift_Nbr":"2"},
 {"ShippingLine_Cd":"CDE","SizeType_Cd":"20DR","ERIStatus_Cd" :"Pending","Shift_Nbr":"3"},
 {"ShippingLine_Cd":"AAC","SizeType_Cd":"20DR","ERIStatus_Cd" :"Active","Shift_Nbr":"1"},
 {"ShippingLine_Cd":"CDE","SizeType_Cd":"20BU","ERIStatus_Cd" :"Pending","Shift_Nbr":"1"}
]
```

This desired **UI format**:

[image: Desired ui format]

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am trying to loop the data for creating the table. Can you suggest any references to do this?

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You could a) write some javascript to do it, or b) search for "jquery plug-in to create tables from data" or similar to see if there is an existing jQuery plug-in that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question shows no code, I will only answer in pseudo code, its up to you to write the real code.

you could do something like this (after you first created your html table):

```
data.forEach(item => {
     var x = item.SizeType_Cd == ("20BU" ? 2 : 0) + item.Shift_Nbr;
     var y = 0; //some logic here to get the y coordinate
     table.children[y].chilren[x].text = item.ERIStatus_Cd; //set the status text
})
```

Comment: I have tried this and can you please give suggestions for better solution. http://jsfiddle.net/rdonthula/FunvZ/288/

Comment: Good, but I am confused. What I did is a basic thing, looping the data and creating the table. Is there any other way to do this in simple way?

Comment: In above solution I want to display toggle control instead of status text. I have tried but it dispalying 'NANANA'. http://jsfiddle.net/rdonthula/FunvZ/290/

Comment: @RajuDonthula Your code looks simple enough, i dont think there is any already made solution for your specific data set. you could try use a viewEngine like react/vue/angular but you'd probably have to change your data set to match the view anyways